# Выдача дублирует некоторые строки

Tags: php, mysql

Есть основной раздел у товара - `shop_items.division_id` и дополнительные `shop_items.divisions` в виде (;1;;2;;3;;4;;5;)

Вторая таблица - `shop_items_sort (item_id, division_id, sort)`

Выдача дублирует некоторые строки и выдает несколько одинаковых.

```
SELECT shop_items.id FROM shop_items LEFT JOIN shop_items_sort as sort ON 
    shop_items.id = sort.item_id and
    (sort.division_id = shop_items.division_id or
    shop_items.divisions like CONCAT('%;', sort.division_id, ';%'))
where shop_items.division_id = "5" or shop_items.divisions like "%;5;%"
```

Comment: значит у вас shop_items_sort у вас содержит несколько одинаковых item_id. Чтобы понять почему так - сделайте вывод всех столбцов и увидите чем строки различаются. Сейчас вам должно помочь `SELECT DISTINCT shop_items.id...` или `SELECT... GROUP BY shop_items.id`

Comment: shop_items_sort 100% не содержит дубликатов, так как через уникальное значение на 2 пол создан. Выдает дубликат - сначала с sort, потом все c sort=0

Comment: я и не говорю, что там дубликаты, но это не значит, что нет одних и тех же item_id, они может division_id различаются - значит уже будет несколько одинаковых записей. И зачем вам `shop_items_sort`, если он все равно не используется? Т.е. раз left join и нет по таблице условия в where, то записи могут отсутствовать, но строки при этом выбираться будут. А раз так, то можно выбросить его из запроса и дубликаты пропадут

Comment: условие order by sort.sort

Comment: `shop_items.divisions like CONCAT('%;', sort.division_id, ';%')` вам выбирает строки из sort по всем отделам, встречающимся в записи. Думаю вот то большое условие в скобках с OR надо заменить на `sort.division_id=5` вам же порядок сортировки только для искомого отдела нужен